# Is "return False" needed after "traceback.print_exc()"?

Tags: python

**My code about this:**

```
try:
    self.cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie(os.environ["HTTP_COOKIE"])
    tmpuid = self.cookie["uid"].value
    tmpsid = self.cookie["sid"].value
except Exception as e:
    if not str(e).startswith('No cookie set'):
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()
    return False
```

**Is "return False" needed after "traceback.print_exc()"?**

Comment: As a general rule, you should put as few lines as possible in the `try` block: otherwise, the code will not raise some useful exceptions. For instance, here, you could have misspelled `"sid"`, and running the code would not show you that you did. Following the same reasoning, it is very useful to only catch the relevant type of exception instead of the generic `Exception`. Both of these points are important for writing robust code.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, The exception only stops on `No cookie set` exceptions.  If it is any other exception the program will `return False` instead of continued to the next statement